# How Can I find the summation of divisors of $n^p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction, natural-numbers, divisor-sum

For Example $n=8$ and $p=2$.
So $n^p=64$.
And the summation of divisors is $1+2+4+8+16+32+64=127$.
But the problem arises when $n=10^6$ and $p=10^6$. 
Remember u can modulus the result by $100$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_m^{k_m}$, where $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ are distinct primes, then the sum of its divisors is
$$
s=\frac{p_1^{k_1+1}-1}{p_1-1}\cdots\frac{p_m^{k_m+1}-1}{p_m-1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Yiorgos S. Smyrlis for your suggestion.
But it cannot fulfill my condition.Because i want to evaluate the summation of n^p not n.

Comment: @Want_to_know, for $n^p$, you can multiply the exponents $k_i$ by $p$ (just replace $n$ by $n^p$).